# dev express grid view combo box default value when binding value is null / empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, razor, devexpress

The following is the combobox code that im using in the dev express grid view edit template.
I want the combobox display nothing at all or a string that says "Please Choose and Employee" while adding a new employee and not when its editing.

```
        @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(edtSettings =>
            {
                edtSettings.Width = 200;
                edtSettings.Name = "EmployeeID";
                //edtSettings.Properties.TextField = "FirstName";
                edtSettings.Properties.ValueField = "EmployeeID";
                edtSettings.Properties.ValueType = typeof(int);

                edtSettings.Properties.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList;
                edtSettings.ShowModelErrors = true;

                edtSettings.Properties.TextFormatString = "{0}" + " " + "{1}";
                edtSettings.Properties.Columns.Add("FirstName", "First Name", 150);
                edtSettings.Properties.Columns.Add("LastName", "Last Name", 150);

                //--- For client side validations
                edtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.IsRequired = true;
                edtSettings.Properties.ValidationSettings.RequiredField.ErrorText = "An Employee must be selected from the list.";

            }).BindList(Model.NonUsers).Bind(Model.UserSingle.EmployeeID).GetHtml()
```

I do this to pass the right Model.UserSingle among other things as follows

```
    var User = ViewData["UserDetail"] != null
                            ? ViewData["UserDetail"]
                            : !c.Grid.IsNewRowEditing
                                ? Model.UserList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.EmployeeID == Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "EmployeeID")))
                                : new User
                                    {
                                        SiteID = (int)Session["siteID"],

                                        ////employee ID cant set to blank, keeps adding a zero
                                        //EmployeeID = Convert.ToInt32(null),

                                        //this is defaulted to 'Timesheet Only'
                                        UserGroupID = 3
                                    };

            Model.UserSingle = (User)User;
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently the MVC ComboBox extension do not allow adding the "Null Item" (Null Text, Water Mark) into the Items collection.
It is in DevEx TO-DO list.

You could try this workaround.

```
 @Html.DevExpress().ComboBox(edtSettings =>
            {
    edtSettings.Properties.ClientSideEvents.Init = "function(s,e){if(s.GetValue()=='0'){ s.SetValue(null);} }";
...
```

Comment: Seems like what I am looking for, I will give this a try in a day or two and let you know how I go. Thanks Alejandro.

Answer (score 1):

In [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) you can use this property:

```
edtSettings.Properties.NullDisplayText = "Please Choose and Employee";
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but I've tried this and this is not what I want.